# Undefined command: "mono_pmip" GDB

Tags: c#, mono, gdb

When trying to analyse a c# coredump file in GDB using mono, I am getting

```
Undefined command: "mono_pmip"
```

I have tried below command inside GDB.

```
1) mono_pmip(0x00007fbe33defe97)
2) .call /usr/bin/mono!mono_pmip(0x00007fbe33defe97)
```

In both the cases I am getting **Undefined command** error.

Started gdb with command

```
gdb <executable_name> <coredump file name>
```

Comment: What is "C# core"?

Comment: @LexLi, it is a core dump.

Comment: .call is a windbg command. With gdb, try `call mono_pmip(0x00007fbe33defe97)`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick with above command I am getting You can't do that without a process to debug. Is there any way I can check the code which was in that address?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about it being a coredump. You can't call functions when looking at a coredump.